# ¿Cómo definir el desplazamiento vertical de una marquee?

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando que una `marquee` se desplaze en vertical a lo largo de una celda de una tabla, pero solo se desplaza el equivalente a su texto, cambiando el tamaño no funciona.

Adjunto el código:

```css
table#transp {
  background-color: transparent;
}

marquee {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<table id="transp">
  <td>
    <table>
      <td>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p id="imp">Como Imprimir</p>
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JcaUYrcpYgo" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe><br/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <audio controls>
              <source src="audio/imprimir.ogg">
            </audio>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </td>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td>
    <marquee direction="up">Recuerda no abrir la bandeja de los cartuchos, la impresora no dejará escanear o imprimir</marquee>
  </td>
</table>
```

Comment: No utilices `marquee`. [Ese elemento está marcado como obsoleto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) y puede dejar de tener soporte en cualquier momento, en su lugar utiliza CSS para animar el texto.

Comment: Aparte, y no relacionado con la pregunta en sí, el código de la pregunta utiliza tablas para maquetar la página. Ese es un método en desuso por ser problemático y poco flexible. Si estás siguiendo un tutorial que diga de utilizar `<marquee>` o maquetación con tablas, mi recomendación sería que pares inmediatamente y busques otros recursos más modernos y apropiados.